Reference Request: Suttas that address avijja (ignorance) with respect to anatta (non-self)
I've become aware through sutta study that avijja (the fetter of ignorance) refers to ignorance of the Four Noble Truths. Is there a specific canonical sutta that says that avijja is ignorance of the anatta doctrine? I know inferentially if anatta is part of the Four Noble Truths, then that would follow, however sometimes the various connections are hard to hold in the mind at the same time.
Thanks.

I don't know of one that explicitly states it, but it almost goes without saying. Just the fact that there is the anatta teaching strongly suggests we're ignorant of it and have to be told. And ignorance is the first link in the chain of dependent arising that leads to the five aggregates and birth, so it's at the root of samsaric existence, especially the sense of self, the base outlook from which we relate to everything else.
But there's a note in my file about AN 6.63 that says, "There are three types of fermentations or taints: Taints of sensuality (kāmāsava), ...becoming (bhavāsava) and ...ignorance (avijjāsava). Abhidhamma adds another taint ...of views (ditthāsava). The fundamental taint... is... ignorance (avijjāsava). This is confirmed in Sammaditthi sutta, when Ven. Sariputta said that ignorance was the cause of all taints." So that would mean ignorance leads to becoming. AN 6.63 says,

Ignorance is the cause by which fermentations come into play. And what is the diversity in fermentations? There are fermentations that lead to hell... the animal womb... the realm of the hungry shades... the human world... the world of the devas. ... One who is immersed in ignorance produces a corresponding state of existence, on the side of merit or demerit.

The same Sammaditthi Sutta (MN 9) implies avijja, anatta and the Four Noble Truths are tied together:

...he extirpates the underlying tendency to the view and conceit 'I am,' and by abandoning ignorance and arousing true knowledge he here and now makes an end of suffering.
 
There are these three kinds of formations: the bodily formation, the verbal formation, the mental formation. With the arising of ignorance there is the arising of formations. With the cessation of ignorance there is the cessation of formations.
 
Not knowing about suffering, not knowing about the origin of suffering, not knowing about the cessation of suffering, not knowing about the way leading to the cessation of suffering — this is called ignorance. With the arising of the taints there is the arising of ignorance. With the cessation of the taints there is the cessation of ignorance. The way leading to the cessation of ignorance is just this Noble Eightfold Path...
 
There are three taints: the taint of sensual desire, the taint of being and the taint of ignorance. With the arising of ignorance there is the arising of the taints. With the cessation of ignorance there is the cessation of the taints.

SN 22.102 connects ignorance with anatta:

When the perception of impermanence is developed and cultivated, it eliminates all sensual lust, it eliminates all lust for existence, it eliminates all ignorance, it uproots all conceit ‘I am’.

MN 75 implies ignorance/delusion leads to self view:

And it would occur to you, 'My gosh, how long have I been fooled, cheated, & deceived by this mind! For in clinging, it was just form that I was clinging to... it was just feeling... just perception... just fabrications... just consciousness that I was clinging to. With my clinging as a requisite condition, there arises becoming... birth... aging & death... sorrow, lamentation, pains, distresses, & despairs. And thus is the origin of this entire mass of stress.'


Did you copy some parts from this blog entry?

I copied the quotes from my Sutta Quotes file, which I mostly copied from accesstoinsight over the years. That page doesn't look familiar, but I must have seen it or an excerpt at some point, because it seems to have some of the exact same wording as the note I pasted.

Somewhat linked, SN35:80 attempts to attack ignorance directly by eliciting a different response or tendency to the habitual tendencies when senses comes into direct contact with phenomena. In a way, the desired effect is similar to perceiving anatta i.e. to disrupt the habitual tendencies that results in clinging or attachment.

I thought there was a sutta directly saying say ignorance is not knowing not-self however I cannot recall or locate it.
MN 115 says regarding any formation as permanent, satisfactory & self is wrong view. However SN 22.154 says wrong view arises from grasping (upadana) rather than is ignorance. Similarly, SN 45.1 says wrong view springs up from ignorance rather than wrong view is ignorance. Similarly, AN 7.11 distinguishes the underlying tendency (anusaya) to wrong views from the underlying tendency to ignorance. Therefore it appears the terms 'ignorance' & 'wrong view' are not exactly synonymous & interchangeable.
MN 2 says the outflow/taint (asava) of ignorance increases when one of six [self] views arises however MN 2 says the outflow of ignorance is abandoned by attending to the Four Noble Truths (leading to stream-entry).
AN 4.49 refers to the perversions of perception, mind & view (saññāvipallāsā cittavipallāsā & diṭṭhivipallāsā) of taking impermanence as permanence, taking unpleasurableness as happiness & taking not-self as self. However, the word 'ignorance' is not found in AN 4.49.
MN 121 says realising impermanence (tadaniccaṁ nirodhadhamman’ti pajānāti) results in the mind freed from the outflow of ignorance (avijjāsavāpi cittaṁ vimuccati). However, MN 121 does not directly say ignorance is not knowing impermanence & not-self.
Lastly, suttas such as SN 22.99 & MN 109 refer to being hindered by ignorance and fettered by craving causing self-views to arise. However, these suttas do not directly say not knowing not-self is ignorance.
All of the above said, not knowing/not realising not-self is certainly ignorance. What else could this not knowing/non-realisation be but ignorance.
